# Что означает ошибка "аргумент типа "size_t" несовместим с параметром типа "zend_string *"?

Tags: php, c

До сих пор переезжаю на PHP7, перенося некоторые расширения.

В одном имеется такой код:

```
if ((zend_hash_update (&module_registry, module_entry->name, strlen(module_entry->name), tmp)) == NULL)
```

На этот аргумент `module_entry->name`

он ругается так:

> аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "zval *"

Сам `module_entry` имеет тип `zend_module_entry *`

Ну ладно, думаю, переназначу его как `(size_t) module_entry->name`, однако при этом он ругается как

> аргумент типа "size_t" несовместим с параметром типа "zend_string *"

Как же это не совместим, если я сую ему что ему надо, а он требует уже другое? Или это я уже устал?)

P. S. Из каких-то сорцов выдрал такую вот функцию:

```
zend_string *str = zval_get_string (module_entry->name);
```

Но она принимает только zval * в качестве аргумента, да и проблему не решает...

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке довольно ясное: второй параметр имеет тип zval *", а вы передаете аргумент module_entry->name , имеющий тип const char *, и нет неявного преобразования из одного типа в другой. Вам надо посмотреть объявление функции и передавать аргументы в соответствии с типами параметров.

Comment: И правда) Определение у нее такое: `zend_hash_update (HashTable *ht, zend_string *key, zval *pData ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC);` Только когда сую ей требуемый zend_string * - пишет "требуется выражение".